# Share between my applications a nonconsumable product bought with In-App purchase?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, share, product

I'd like to develop several iPhone applications that will allow an user to buy nonconsumable products using the In-App Purchase feature.

Is it possible that these applications share the same products?

Let's take this example to be clearer. User buys product1 from app1 using IAP. Could app2 restore product1 when calling *restoreCompletedTransactions* of the *SKPaymentQueue*?

Or should the user buys twice the products ; one time for app1 and one time for app2?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can do this if the applications have the same bundle ID, as you write to the same sandbox. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: No it will not work as they will be separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the custom URL scheme mechanism to call your "sibling" apps and pass them a token representing the purchase. They'll each need to deal with that purchase themselves (downloding something or unlocking something or whatever you do), but they can all share the FACT of the purchase, which is really all in-app purchasing is.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you implicitly say that one product could only be linked to one application for the In-App Purchase. That's right ?

Comment: I believe that's the case, yes.